# What is meant by drug tolerance?

Tags: neuroscience, pharmacology

What is meant by drug tolerance?

This question is in my biology textbook for IGCSE and I have no idea what drug tolerance is. It would be very helpful if someone could clarify. Thank you.

Comment: Have you read the article in the Wikipedia about it? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drug_tolerance Do you have specific questions about it?

Comment: Yes I did but I still couldn't get a clear picture of it in my head.

Comment: Would you happen to know another site with a clearer definition?

Comment: Can you tell us what you find unclear in this definition? This makes writing a meaningful answer easier.

Comment: "when a subject's reaction to a specific drug and concentration of the drug is progressively reduced, requiring an increase in concentration to achieve the desired effect."

Comment: Does this mean the more the user takes the drug, more of it is needed for him to achieve a high?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It basically means, that the body gets used to certain drugs and that you need to raise the dose to reach an effect. This is for example true for a number of anesthetics or pain medications as morphine.

Permanent application leads to a down-regulation of the drug receptor (for morphin this is the mu-opiod receptor) and the activation of counteracting signaltransduction pathways. To still get an activation you will need a higher drug concentration.
For more details have a look at these articles:

- [Opiate tolerance and dependence: receptors, G-proteins, and
  antiopiates](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/9864069)
- [Cellular neuroadaptations to chronic opioids: tolerance, withdrawal
  and addiction](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1038/bjp.2008.100/full)